# Want to use native C libraries in a web application, what are my options?

Tags: c++, c, html, web-applications, libraries

I have many legacy C libraries used for numerical analysis and scientific computing (e.g. simulation) that I want to use in a web application I am building (so far I have only been using Javascript to make a user interface). What options do I have in doing this on the client side and/or the server side? I heard about using native client with chrome, but I dislike that the client has to turn on the native client flag to do this.

Comment: The question is where the "numerical analysis and scientific computing" should be placed - on client- or server-side? You have such a choice in a web-application. But you should provide more details for others about the app if you want they help you.

Comment: Calling the C code "legacy" is probably not going to win you fans among folks who follow the `c` tag unless you just meant that it's C code written in old/bad style (like global variables, `#ifdef` hell, nonportable constructs and undefined behavior, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On **Server Side**:

To begin with CGI (Common Gateway Interface) is the most basic method to be able to use native C libraries in a web application - wherein you delegate an executable (say written in C) to generate the sever side web content.

But CGI is very primitive and inefficient. Each command can result in creation of a new `Process` on the server. Thus here are other viable alternates:

1. Apache Modules let you run third party software within the web server itself.
2. [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) - Single Process handles more than one user request.
3. [SCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Common_Gateway_Interface) - Simple CGI

Refer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Alternatives

On **Client Side**:

Good News & Bad News:

You can use PNaCl (Portable Native Client) in chrome. It **will be** turned on by default.
BUT the first public release is *expected* in late 2013.[Look for PNaCl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client)

Comment: The inefficiency of CGI is highly exaggerated; on modern systems, starting a new process takes roughly the same amount of time as opening, reading, and closing a moderate-sized file (like one you might be serving on a webserver). This is a lot less time than the overhead of most script language interpreters/runtimes.

Comment: But I still think - a lot of requests will result in a **lot** of processes simultaneously - that can cause some real strain on the server.

Comment: I would test before making assumptions. In my experience, external CGI (even running a perl interpreter) served off thttpd was an order of magnitude faster than mod_perl in Apache.

Comment: Roger that; testing first - sounds good - but anyway - FastCGI wherein the same process keeps running for a long time to handle more than one request, should get over this limitation.

Comment: I want to add here that I node.js based servers have a nice way of calling server side processes too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much on the client side - there's no way you can expect the client to have these libraries, and no safe way to download and run them.

The simplest way is to write your server side any way you want, and access them through a web interface.   Many languages customarily used for server side scripting can access native C libraries, or you can even write ordinary C applications and run them as scripting agents.

In the "really exotic" category, it is possible to run what starts as C code in the client
if you embed it in a sufficiently protected environment.  For example, see the description
of how sqlite (a C database application) was made into a 100% pure java application by
embedding a mips simulator written in java.

http://blog.benad.me/2008/1/22/nestedvm-compile-almost-anything-to-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Looked at `Wt` yet? Its pretty neat.

Also you have options to code in cgi(ugly).

Although not C, its written in C++. If you can ignore that part: [Wt at your service](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)

Answer (score 0):

For doing it client-side, you can use [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki). However, this will most probably require some refactoring of your existing code to fit JavaScript's asynchronous main loop requirement.

Note that Emscripten isn't a proof of concept or something like that. It *is* very powerful and already used to port complex code to the web. You can take a look at the demos (listed in the above URL) to see what can be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're best off to represent your legacy C library methods as a kind of (WEB) service at the server side. A raw CGI application seems to be a pretty low level point for this approach, but is generally right.
There are C/C++ frameworks available to create webservice servers, and client side libraries that support webservice access and data representation. For the server side you could use [gSoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use the webserver of your choice to transmit ordinary files and use a custom webserver (which wouldn't need to support the full HTTP spec) wired up to your C code to communicate with client-side Javascript.

Two minimal webservers you could use as base are [libuv-webserver](https://github.com/philips/libuv-webserver) and [nweb](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-nweb/).